# Dificuldade do php pegar texto do select alimentado com javascript e json

Tags: php, javascript, json

O código javascript abaixo, preenche as opções do select "regioes" (id) do arquivo json "lista-regiao-programas-municipio". 
Mas no form html este preenche o value com valor do ID no json. E se mudar não funciona o select.

```js
HtmlOption += '<option value="' + select.id + '">' + select.name + '</option>';
```

Como faço para o php pegar o texto?

Form html

```html
<form method="POST" action="SIGPLAM4/cadastro.php" role="form">

<div class="form-group" role="select">
     <label for="regioes">RegiÃ£o de integraÃ§Ã£o</label>
     <select name="regioes" id="regioes">
         <option value="">Selecione a regiÃ§Ã£o</option>
      </select>
 </div>

<div class="form-group" role="selecet">
       <!-- selecionar o programa -->
       <label for="programas">Programa desenvolvido</label>
       <select name="programas" id="programas">
          <option value="">Selecione o programa</option>
       </select>
</div>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Cadastrar">
```

Arquivo: alimentar-combos-regiao-programas-municipio.js

```js
function get_json_data(id, parent_id) {
  var HtmlOption = '';

  $.getJSON('SIGPLAM4/javaScript/lista-regiao-programas-municipio.json', function(data){
ListSelect = id;  // ID do select regioes do form html
HtmlOption += '<option value="">Selecione a ' + ListSelect + '</option>';

// alimenta o objeto select usando each e, uma função anônima de callback (índice do objeto e o objeto)
$.each(data, function(key, select) {
  if(select.parent_id == parent_id) {
    HtmlOption += '<option value="' + select.id + '">' + select.name + '</option>';
  }
});
$('#' + id).html(HtmlOption); // envia as opções do select do arquivo json ao form html
  });
}
get_json_data('regioes', 0);

$(document).on('change', '#regioes', function(){  // quando uma opção é selecionada no select regioes, alimenta os outros selects do form
  var regioes_id = $(this).val();

  if (regioes_id != ''){
get_json_data('programas', regioes_id);
get_json_data('municipio', category_id);
get_json_data('municipioSuas', category_id);
get_json_data('municipioVig', category_id);
  } else {
$('#programas').html('<option value="">Selecione o programa</option>');
  }
});

$(document).on('change', '#programas', function(){
  var category_id = $(this).val();
  if (category_id != '') {
get_json_data('municipio', category_id);
get_json_data('municipioSuas', category_id);
get_json_data('municipioVig', category_id);
  } else {
$('#municipio').html('<option value="">Selecione o municipio</option>');
$('#municipioSuas').html('<option value="">Selecione o municipio SUAS</option>');
$('#municipioVig').html('<option value="">Selecione o municipio VIG</option>');
  }
});
```

Arquivo lista-regiao-programas-municipio.json

```js
[
   {
  "id":"1",
  "name":"Araguaia",
  "parent_id":"0"
   },
   {
  "id":"2",
  "name":"Baixo Amazonas",
  "value":"Baixo Amazonas",
  "parent_id":"0"
   },
   {
  "id":"3",
  "name":"CarajÃ¡s",
  "parent_id":"0"
   },
   

   {
  "id":"4",
  "name":"Programa 1",
  "parent_id":"1"
   },
   {
  "id":"5",
  "name":"Programa 2",
  "parent_id":"1"
   },
   {
  "id":"6",
  "name":"Programa 3",
  "parent_id":"1"
   },
   
   
   {
  "id":"7",
  "name":"Agua Azul do Norte",
  "parent_id":"4"
   },
   {
  "id":"8",
  "name":"Bannach",
  "parent_id":"4"
   },
   {
  "id":"9",
  "name":"Conceição do Araguaia",
  "parent_id":"4"
   },
   
   
   {
  "id":"10",
  "name":"Agua Azul do Norte",
  "parent_id":"5"
   },
   {
  "id":"11",
  "name":"Bannach",
  "parent_id":"5"
   },
   {
  "id":"12",
  "name":"Conceição do Araguaia",
  "parent_id":"5"
   }
]
```

Um PHP simples

```php
if (isset($_POST['regioes']) ? $_POST['regioes'] : null){
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui a solução unindo dois procedimentos (getjson + método barroco switch case)

Ao escolher no select "regioes" alimenta o select "programas" com getjson:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $.getJSON('javaScript/lista-regiao-programas.json', function(data){
      var items = [];
      var options = '<option value="">escolha um estado</option>';
      $.each(data, function(key, val){
         options += '<option value="' + val.nome + '">' + val.nome + '</option>';
      });
         $("#regioes").html(options);
       $("#regioes").change(function(){
         var options_cidades = '';
         var str = "";
          $("#regioes option:selected").each(function(){
           str += $(this).text();
         });
         $.each(data, function(key, val){
            if(val.nome == str){
               $.each(val.cidades, function (key_city, val_city){
                    options_cidades += '<option value="' + val_city + '">' + val_city + '</option>';
               });
            }
         });
      
         $("#programas").html(options_cidades);
      }).change();
   });
});
```

Também ao escolher no select "regioes" alimenta o select "municipio" com switch case arcaico:

```js
function dynamicdropdown(listindex)
{
  switch (listindex)
  {
  case "Araguaia" :
    document.getElementById("municipio").options[0]=new Option("Selecione o município","");
    document.getElementById("municipio").options[1]=new Option("Conceição do Araguaia","Conceição do Araguaia");
    document.getElementById("municipio").options[2]=new Option("Floresta do Araguaia","Floresta do Araguaia");
    document.getElementById("municipio").options[3]=new Option("Santa Maria das Barreiras","Santa Maria das Barreiras");
    document.getElementById("municipio").options[4]=new Option("Santana do Araguaia","Santana do Araguaia");
    break;
  case "Baixo Amazonas" :
    document.getElementById("municipio").options[0]=new Option("Selecione o município","");
    document.getElementById("municipio").options[1]=new Option("Município 1","Município 1");
    document.getElementById("municipio").options[2]=new Option("Município 2","Município 2");
    break;
  }
  return true;
}
```

O form select html:

```html
<label for="regioes">Região de integração</label>
<select name="regioes" id="regioes" class="form-control" onchange="javascript: dynamicdropdown(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
      <option value="">Selecione a regiÃ§Ã£o</option>
</select>
  
 <label for="programas">Programa desenvolvido</label>
<select name="programas" id="programas" class="form-control">
     <option value="">Selecione o programa</option>
</select>

<label for="municipio">Município de atuação</label>
<select name="municipio" id="municipio">
        <option value="">Selecione o municipio</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

Sua pergunta é

> Como faço para o php pegar o texto?

A questão está muito vaga.

Você quer pegar o texto selecionado no combobox e enviar para a página do cadastro? Quando você envia o formulário através de POST a informação enviada pelo combobox é a que está no "value" da opção selecionada. Pra enviar o texto da região pelo formulário você deve preencher o campo "value" do option com "select.name", mas não faz muito sentido enviar o nome.

De todo jeito existem inúmeras formas de enviar a informação. Falta só você dizer o objetivo de "fazer o php pegar o texto"

Comment: '<option value="' + select.id + '">' + select.name + '</option>'; Eu achei esse código na net. No original o value está recebendo o "select.id" e o "post" php salva um número no mysql...

Mas se eu mudar p/ "select.value" o select programas e select municipio do form não são alimentado com o as opções do json. Mudando o "post" php salva o texto no mysql mas os outros selects ficam em branco.

Comment: Pelo que você disse, você não pode mudar o "select.id" para que seu sistema continue funcionando. Qual a sua dúvida então? Você quer mostrar o nome da região depois que o registro estiver salvo? Se for isso, você não deve mudar o código do formulário. Você deve mudar o código que mostra a informação.

Comment: Eu não posso mudar o "select.id" do comando abaixo pois o sistema para de funcionar HtmlOption += '<option value="' + select.id + '">' + select.name + '</option>';


Então onde eu coloco o "select.value" no javascript $.each ? Eu preciso salvar o "value" ou o "name" do select no mysql. Pois como está salva apenas o número do "select.id"